# Uploading tif to GEE Error: "Image extends outside -90,90 latitude range. Bounding box x=0..43200, y=0..16800"

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, latitude-longitude, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

[image: Proof of 4326 projection of the raster.]

I had a vrt layer of soils that I'd like to use in GEE. Since GEE only takes tif image files for upload to assets, I exported it as a tif with the projection EPSG:4326. However, when I try uploading it to GEE, I get the error below:

**Error: Image extends outside the [-90, 90] latitude range by more than one pixel. Found Bounding box (x=0..43200, y=0..16800) (Error code: 3)**

How do I transform my raster tif to be within the -90 to 90 latitude range so that I can upload it to GEE if it's already in the correct projection? It seems like it's using the dimensions of the VRT as the coordinates for some reason.

Comment: The message literally tells you the error: **`Bounding box (x=0..43200, y=0..16800)`**. Check again, looks like a projected CRS. EPSG:4326 has -90 to 90 latitude range and -180 to 180 longitude range. This is a way out of this range

Comment: I realize it's out of range, but the raster file says its in EPSG:4326 which should be correct and I am not sure how to fix it from here. I've added an image above.

Comment: Check each step of this raster creation, maybe you assigned a lat/long projection over a projected layer

Comment: It's not out of range. The raster hasn't been georeferenced. Those are pixel coordinates.

Comment: Oooh, that is extremely helpful. How would I go about georeferencing the pixel coordinate raster to the vrt layer?

Comment: Or- even better, is there a way to make it maintain being georeferenced when exporting from vrt to tif?